# Multiple foreign keys in SQLAlchemy ORM model

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have one table languages, that stores list of available Languages:

```
id:1, language:"english"
id:2, language:"spanish"
id:3, language:"italian"
```

I want to have hose language names to be translated, for that purpose i have created another Table called LanguageTranslation:

```
id:1, language_id:1, translated_to:2, translation:"inglesa"  (English in Spanish)
id:2, language_id:1, translated_to:3, translation:"inglese"  (English in Italian)
id:3, language_id:2, translated_to:3, translation:"spagnola"  (Spanish in Italian)
```

For that purpose i have included two foreign keys from Parent to Child tables:

```
class Language(Base):
    __tablename__ = "languages"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    language: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), nullable=False)
    translations: Mapped[List["LanguageTranslation"]] = relationship(back_populates="language")
    
class LanguageTranslation(Base):
    __tablename__ = "language_translations"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    language_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("languages.id"), nullable=False)
    translated_to: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("languages.id"), nullable=False)
    language: Mapped["Language"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[language_id])
    translated: Mapped["Language"] = relationship(foreign_keys=[translated_to])
    translation: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(64), nullable=False)
```

However, when i try to build tables in SQLAlchemy, it gives the following error:

```
raise sa_exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError(
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Language.translations - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Kindly, advise what am I doing wrong or how can I implement above task in a right way?

Comment: Going by the back_populates you have shown, did you mean `translations: Mapped[List["LanguageTranslation"]] = relationship(back_populates="language", foreign_keys='[LanguageTranslation.language_id]')`?